# Scale texts as the the parent shape layer changes

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

can anyone take a look at the animation I've made and provide some insights?
Here is what I've got so far.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eIdcAp9cK_AaA8UWBx9OKWAXXZWq0F2r/view?usp=sharing

The problem: texts are floating when the cube is rotating.

Current method: I have a cube animation as the background and I added shaper layer and text to each face. For each face, I parent the text to shape layer and use path to adjust the shape as the cube rotating.

Question: is there a better way to scale the text correspondingly as parent shape layer resizing?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the cube animation as a rendered file and can't mess around in the original animation, I would try corner-pins. Simply track the corners by hand by keyframing the four corners of the corner-pin to the corners of each face and apply it to your text layer. You might want to precomp the text first and apply the corner-pin onto the precomp, so you're able to rescale and modify the text alone from inside the precomp.